# Is there a VS plugin for convert a JSON string to an InnerClassEntity class , just like GsonFormat

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

I am a android developer , i am new to vs , i want to develop android app with C# recently, but i can not find any plugin that can convert a JSON string to an InnerClassEntity class, just like GsonFormat, can any one help me , thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are not Visual Studio plugins but can convert JSON to C# classes for cut/pasting into your solution/project, not as nice as using GSONFormat within Android Studio, but it can help get the job done.

[JSON C# Class Generator](http://jsonclassgenerator.codeplex.com)

[image]

Or:

Browser based: [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com)

For consuming JSON within your app, Newtonsoft's Json.NET is very popular:

- http://www.newtonsoft.com/json
- Nuget search : `Json.NET`

Comment: CodePlex is gone :(

Answer (score 7):

No Plugin needed! It's built into Visual Studio. Just copy the json into the clipboard and then `Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON as Classes`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I always use [Json2CSharp](http://json2csharp.com/) for converting my Json to C# Classes. You can either copy and paste your entire JSON string or provide the URL to the JSON. This online tool is highly compatible with [JSON.NET (Newtonsoft JSON)](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library, which is mostly used in all .NET technologies for serializing and de-serializing JSON.