# Generate nested JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to generate this nested json via c# objects

```
{
  "contest": {
    "name": "eatfast"
  },
  "contestants": {
    "player": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "KILL",
        "stats": {
          "time": 5
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "BILL",
        "stats": {
          "time": 16
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Heres what I have

```
private static string FormatJson(string json)
        {
            dynamic parsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parsedJson, Formatting.Indented);
        }

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string json = "{\"contest\": { \"name\": \"eatfast\"},\"contestants\":  {\"player\": [";

    Contestants test = new Contestants
    {
        id = 3,
        name = "JESUS"
        //stats;
    };

    json = json + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test, Formatting.Indented) + "]}}" ;
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText("test.txt", FormatJson(json));
}
```

Output

```
{
  "contest": {
    "name": "eatfast"
  },
  "contestants": {
    "player": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "JESUS"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Could you give me any ideas on how to add a player in this example, or how to add stats time, appreciate any help

Or should I do it manually using string manipulation?

Comment: you could try this tool: [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/) and paste your json there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I turn a C# object into a JSON string in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/how-do-i-turn-a-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to auto-generate a C# class file from a JSON object string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21611674/how-to-auto-generate-a-c-sharp-class-file-from-a-json-object-string)

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36983311/is-there-a-vs-plugin-for-convert-a-json-string-to-an-innerclassentity-class-ju

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create JSON string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056121/how-to-create-json-string-in-c-sharp)

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34043384/easiest-way-to-parse-json-response

Comment: I guess OP wants to serialize object to json, not json to object.

Comment: @SeM, what If I told you it's the same thing. In most documentation Serializing and Deserializing,  are on the same documentation page. In fact the complete code for Serializing and Deserializing, differs by 2 chars.

Comment: @DragandDrop _"In same documentation page"_ is not an enough criteria to accept something as "same thing".

Answer (score 0):

As per comment this is what your class would look like ([json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/))

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Contest contest { get; set; }
    public Contestants contestants { get; set; }
}

public class Contest
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}   

public class Player
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Stats stats { get; set; }
}

public class Stats
{
    public int time { get; set; }
}

public class Contestants
{
    public List<Player> player { get; set; }
}
```

All got to do then is using [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) (available via NuGet):

```
RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(yourjsonString);
```

and

```
RootObject obj = new RootObject(); //proper initialisation of your object needed
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

Comment: why randomly downvoting everything ?!

Comment: Probably someone who doesn't approve of "give me the code" kind of questions. I'm not sure why those people downvote good answers, though. I guess it's because they feel that the question shouldn't be answered at all.

Comment: @John yeah I guess that's the case. I still think even if the question is "give me code" ppl and the OP itself can still learn from those answers...

Comment: Or the fact that 80% of C# json question have exactly this answer and question.

Comment: @DragandDrop i am to blame for answering a question that is a duplicate :D ?

Comment: @DragandDrop so why dont u guys instead of downvoting me flag the question as a dupe :D ?

Comment: kinda https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled, but im on page 7 of Google can't find an adequate duplicate with both json to csharp and PAste special answer and dynamyc type.